# Pin Ubuntu major LTS version but allow minor upgrade?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

Does anyone know how I can pin my Ubuntu to accept only minor version upgrade (e.g. 16.04.x)?  If I set in Software & Updates, notify me of a new Ubuntu version to "For long-term support version", it looks like it will try to upgrade me to 18.04.1 LTS.

So is there a way to keep minor version update while skipping major (e.g. 16 -> 18) update?

Comment: What you call a "minor upgrade", as well as "minor version update" is called a point release. It is usually an accumulation of updates, and the release version goes from 16.04 to 16.04.1 or similar. This is done simply by applying regular updates, and there is no special notification.  What you call a "major update" is just an upgrade, and you are free to opt out, by selecting to never offer an upgrade. To summarize, there is no need to pin anything, just apply daily updates, and opt out of upgrades.

Comment: Thanks @mikewhatever you have answered my question; I think you put it in a comment as I can't mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"New Ubuntu version" there means a new *major* version, like 16.04 to 16.10 or 16.04 to 18.04. Change it to notify you of a new Ubuntu version never.

Just remember to upgrade Ubuntu before the major version (16.04 in your case) is five years old (three years if you use an Ubuntu flavor, like Xubuntu, rather than regular Ubuntu), because then security updates get cut off.

The minor point changes like 16.04.1 to 16.04.2 come automatically with normal everyday software updates. You don't need to do anything special to get those.